# How legal is this operation in ruby? Appending a value directly to a function call

Tags: ruby, recursion

I have come across this recursive implementation of range using Ruby and I was trying to understand how we can append values straight into a recursive call? Can someone explain to me what is happening under the hood?

Here is the implementation:

```
def range(min, max)
  return [] if max <= min
  range(min, max - 1) << max - 1
end
```

Comment: Recursive call returns value of type array, so we appending value to the result of the recursive call.

Comment: Unless it's written purely for academic purposes, this is a really bad/pointless method. It's called `range` and yet returns an `Array` (not a `Range`). And it could instead just be implemented as: `(min..max).to_a`, instead of this fancy recursion. But in all likelihood, simply using `(min..max)` would suit your needs rather than having an `Array` at all!

Comment: It was for academic purposes aimed at understanding recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can someone explain to me what is happening under the hood?

You can trace the recusion. If you call `range(1, 4)` the result will be `range(1, 3) << 3`. But in order to evaluate that, we need the result for `range(1, 3)` which is `range(1, 2) << 2` and so on. If you write down each iteration you'll get:

```
                   range(1, 4)
              range(1, 3) << 3
       (range(1, 2) << 2) << 3
((range(1, 1) << 1) << 2) << 3
```

At this point, you have `range(1, 1)` which has a return value of `[]` because `1 <= 1` is true – the method's first line. The recursion ends and can finally be evaluated as:

```
         (([] << 1) << 2) << 3
               ([1] << 2) << 3
                   [1, 2] << 3
                     [1, 2, 3]
```

---

When writing recursive methods, you often want to implement them in a [tail-recursive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) way, because it can be [optimized](https://nithinbekal.com/posts/ruby-tco/).

*Tail-recursive* means that your method's last expression is a call to itself, e.g.:

```
def range(min, max, result = [])
  return result if max <= min
  range(min, max - 1, result.unshift(max - 1))
end
```

Note that the last line merely invokes `range` again, just with different arguments. I had to add an extra argument `result` which stores the accumulated values and which eventually becomes the method's final result.

It would be evaluated as: (I've right-aligned it to make `unshift` more obvious)

```
range(1, 4,        [])
range(1, 3,       [3])
range(1, 2,    [2, 3])
range(1, 1, [1, 2, 3])
[1, 2, 3]
```

Unfortunately, `unshift` is a rather expensive operation. It would be faster to `push` the values and then [`reverse`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Array.html#reverse-method) the result:

```
def range(min, max, result = [])
  return result.reverse if max <= min
  range(min, max - 1, result.push(max - 1))
end
```

Step by step:

```
range(1, 4, [])
range(1, 3, [3])
range(1, 2, [3, 2])
range(1, 1, [3, 2, 1])
[1, 2, 3]
```

Or alternatively, push an incremented `min` instead of a decremented `max` which populates `result` in the correct order:

```
def range(min, max, result = [])
  return result if max <= min
  range(min + 1, max, result.push(min))
end
```

Which becomes:

```
range(1, 4, [])
range(2, 4, [1])
range(3, 4, [1, 2])
range(4, 4, [1, 2, 3])
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: +1 for the nice illustration, are StackErrors avoidable in Ruby recursive calls for large input even after optimization?

Comment: @Fnechz you don't get stack overflow error with tail call optimization because the stack frame is reused.

Comment: @Stefan TCO isn't active by default in MRI.

Comment: @coreyward I know. That’s why I added a link to that blog post.

Answer (score 3):

The `<<` operator is implemented as a method. This is actually syntactic sugar, so it's more like calling `range(…).<<`. This is just like method chaining, so the `<<` method is actually being called on the return value of `range`, which appears to be an array. So it's calling `Array#<<`.

For what it's worth, this is an awful construct. Ruby doesn't do recursion well (unless you enable Tail Call Optimization), and it's hard to read. Much better to simply use the built in `Range` object:

```rb
some_range = 1..7
some_range_excluding_final_value = 1...7

# or if you really need an array:
(1..7).to_a
```

Comment: I get that, the base case of the recursive method determines the return type?

Comment: Recursive methods return tail first, like Rack middleware. In this case, the last time this method gets called will be with a `max` value that is equal to the `min` value, in which case `[]` is returned to the caller, which calls `<<(max - 1)` on it and returns it, and so on, until the original method calling `range` gets a response.